# Magento - What are the diferences between an EAV attribute in the entity and attribute in its table type

Tags: database, magento, optimization, entity-attribute-value

I have the next doubt:

In the EAV data structure you can find an attribute in the entity or in the table of the associated type.

For Example:

catalog_product_entity

```
| entity_id | entity_type_id | attribute_set_id | type_id |   sku   | has_option | ....
|     1     |        4       |       34         |  simple | 0912132 |    0       |
```

catalog_product_entity_datetatime

```
| value_id  |  entity_type_id | attribute_id  | store_id | entity_id | value
|    1      |       4         |      71       |    0     |     1     |  NULL
```

catalog_product_entity_decimal

```
 | value_id  |  entity_type_id | attribute_id  | store_id | entity_id |value 
 |    1      |       4         |     69        |   1      |    1      | 29.009
```

you can find the attribute sku in the flat table catalog_product_entity, and the attribute_id **71** and **69** in the tables **catalog_product_entity_datatime** and **catalog_product_entity_decimal**

Why is the attribute sku in the entity table? is it because of optimization reasons?

If I want to improve the load of an attribute, could I insert it in the entity table? What is a reasonable number of attributes in the entity table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These attributes (with type static) are necessary in order to do a proper save of any EAV object without overwriting the `save()` method or other methods involved in the save for each entity type.
You can take a look at this method `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_collectSaveData()`. All EAV entity models extend `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract` and that method is called when saving an instance.
All the static attribtues are added to the array `$entityRow`. this means that they will be saved in the main table but you still have the option to attach a `backend_model` to the static attribute that will process the value to be saved, before the actual save is done.

Comment: Hi Marius, Thanks for you answer. Where I can search information in depth of eav in Magento? can you show me some additional information?

Comment: @davidselo. Start with this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-7-advanced-orm-entity-attribute-value. The rest you find out by getting your hands dirty with code.